# Twitter requests - the right way

Tags: php, twitter

I am currently requesting a twitter feed on each page load (I know this is wrong) like this:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}"));
```

Even with minimal traffic, twitter stops sending me the request before long. So after launching the website for my client - I am seeing perpetually unavailable twitter feeds.

The way I am imagining this working is checking the feed - storing it in a table with a timestamp, and choosing an interval - (say 10 minutes). On each pageload, check the timestamp, if the interval has not passed, pull the feed from the table, rather than twitter.

I know this would work, but given my last mistake being so silly, I wanted to make sure that there wasn't another better practice.

Do I have it right this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds exactly right. Three notes:

1. Put the date/time in one column and the twitter feed you want to show in another column, then you can just do a single select on that row and be done with it.
2. Store the rendered HTML in the database, not the JSON returned from Twitter. Then you're only doing the transformation every ten minutes and not on every page request.
3. Do the time comparison all in the database or all on the server, don't mix the two - I've run into problems with servers out of time sync that caused me big headaches. That is, don't use a "INSERT ... CURTIME() ..." call and then compare that with a PHP generated date. My suggestion would be to generate a PHP date and store that, since time comparison in SQL can be tricky.

Comment: You make excellent points. Thanks a ton, especially with comparing the time - I never would have thought of that. Is there an easy way to compare time inside the database? I was planning on having a column default to the current timestamp.

Comment: Short answer, no. I would store the return value of PHP's time() and not bother with the database time functions at all. That value is in seconds, so after you retrieve the timestamp you can compare with something like `if (time() > ($timestamp + (10 * 60))) ...`

Comment: If you're doing a lot of in-table date comparison, using date column types and then converting to a unix timestamp with `strtotime()` could also be a good way to handle dates. It is a good idea not to interchange too much. Also note, you have `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in MySQL if you need it. PHP also has `mktime()`, which gives you the same thing as `time()`, and newer versions of PHP have the [`DateTime`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

Answer (score 1):

It's always smart to cache I/O data that isn't likely to have changed.  The optimal way depending on the amount of traffic you get and how current you need the data.